# Get Millis using only Year and Month

Tags: javascript

I need to get a MILLIS value only with Year and Month.

Important: I don't wanna to use Days, Hours, Seconds, etc.

I'm using the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    var d = new Date(date);
    d.setMonth(i);
    var span = $("<span>").addClass("calElement").attr("millis", d.getTime());
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `I need to get a MILLIS value only with Year and Month.`? Can you give us an example of what you're looking to return?

Comment: What's `date`? What's "millis"? Can you explain your needs with some sample data rather that some DOM code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct a new date using the given year and a month from the loop, time is automatically set to `00:00:00.000`.

```
var y = new Date(date).getFullYear(),
    msecs = new Date(y, i, 1).getTime();
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61sdos94/).

If you want to include the `month[i]`, just loop from `1` to `12`.

Comment: You're wellcome. I wasn't sure, if you'd have needed [monthly elapsed time](http://jsfiddle.net/61sdos94/1/) instead.